# django queryset - need advice on queryset in view - filters and setting relationships

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to generate a template/report that lists all of the listings (ads) for a customer.  Most everything relates to the ID of the Listings table.  A customer can have many listings, a listing will only have one listing type, and a listing can have many images.  I know my `view.py` is messed up -- ideally I'd like to send a minimal amount of data to the template.  So I would like to only send listings, images and listingtype (1, 2, or 3) data that relates to listings for a specific customer.  I'm struggling with the queryset, and building the context.  I'm sure I have to add more objects to the context than are currently listed.

I'm am presuming once I get the data to the template I will have to build a table row by row, and do some if/then stuff in the template to deal with the different listingtypes.  Let me know if you know of an easier way.

Models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

class ListingType(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.desc

class Listings(models.Model):
    createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    listing_type = models.ForeignKey(ListingType)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class Listingtype1(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    mfg_no = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    typespecific1 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    typespecific2 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)

class Listingtype2(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    mfg_no = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    typespecific1 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    typespecific2 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)

class Listingtype3(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    mfg_no = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    typespecific1 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    typespecific2 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)
```

Views.py (work in progress)

```
def listings_customer(request, user_id):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=user_id)
    cusnum=customer.id
    listings = Listings.objects.filter(customer=cusnum)
    image = Image.objects.all()
    context=Context({
        'title': 'Listings',
        'customer': customer,
        'listings' : listings,        
        'image' : image,        
        })
    return render_to_response('bsmain/listings.html', context)
```

Comment: What's the relationship between ListingType and Listingtype1?

Comment: none - but I noticed from your question that I had not included Listings in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [lookups with relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and [backwards relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#how-are-the-backward-relationships-possible) so you can link all your models in chains like:

```
Image.objects.filter(listings__customer=customer)
```

Also, few offtopic advices.

> a listing will only have one listing type

So you should use OneToOneField here

You don't need to retrieve `customer.id`, use `customer` for lookup.

Use non-plural names for your models (`Listings` should be `Listing`) and avoid duplicating your code like in `ListingType1` and `ListingType2`, use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Comment: ilvar - thanks, I see your points, I have not been able to understand where there is a particular advantage to using a onetoone field, or disadvantage to using a Foreignkey.  I suppose it makes the relationships more obvious when looking at models.  The non-plural comment is good, that has been bothering me too.  The Listingtype1 ..2...3 were for posting purposes only, in reality the tables for the different lising types are very different.

Comment: In database FK anf OTO fields are the same, with only automatic `unique=True` on OTO. But OTO fields have much compact backwards relation (`ListingType.listing` instead of `ListingType.listing_set.all()[0]`) and is more readable (which is the most important). In any part of code you should take into consideration that some other programmer will need to work with this code, and you will not be available to explain why it is the way it is.